# Ini4j.jar doesnt work with registry file in java

Tags: java

After adding new section to reg file with key and value, using the store() method to save changes in the file, The new section is added in parts more then once.
my code:

```
File file = new File("2.reg");
Reg reg = new Reg(file);
Key key = reg.add("AA\BB\CC");
key.add("dd","dd");
reg.store();
```

after store() the reg file has 3 new levels and looks like:

```
[AA]
[AA\BB]
[AA\BB\CC]
"dd"="dd"
```

If there is key=empty string like: "vv"="", after load() the string is changed without the value-> "vv"= and the file cannot be loaded again:

```
File file = new File("2.reg");
Reg reg = new Reg(file);
Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
An exception occurred: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

please help.
Thanks

Comment: I am quite surprised by the result, since this --> `reg.add("AA\BB\CC");` <-- cannot compile in Java (you need to double the backslashes)

Comment: Please state your problem in clear terms what you want to do actually?

Comment: Key key = reg.add("AA\BB\CC");

Comment: correct, the line is: Key key = reg.add("AA\\BB\\CC"); and the result the same as before

Answer (score 1):

Key key = reg.add("AA\BB\CC");

This line of your code wont be compile because it contains escape character (sequence)

[check this link for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: correct, the line is: Key key = reg.add("AA\\BB\\CC");                                    and the result the same as before